# Problem with URL or MalFormedURLException

Tags: java, url

I am trying to find the number of words in the website.

But when I run it I keep getting:

**...cannot find symbol**

**catch(MalFormerdURLException ex)**

I imported the necessary packages and it's still not working

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class CountWords{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String URL = "http://websitetips.com/articles/copy/lorem/ipsum.txt";
        URL url;

        try{
            url = new URL(URL);
            int count = 0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while(input.hasNext()){
                String line = input.nextLine();
                count += line.length();
            }

            System.out.println(count);
        }

        catch(MalFormedURLException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid URL");
        }

        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("IO Errors");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you typed it wrong.  It should be `MalformedURLException` with `f`, not `F`

Comment: @KunLun Ah thank you. It's always the small things I don't see